# Match hyperlink

Tags: c#, regex

How can I match a hyperlink starting with `https://` and ending with `.mp4`?

For example I would like to match `https://examle.com/abc.mp4` from the following string. However, with pattern `https://.*?\.mp4` the previous hyperlinks are also matched (shown in bold).

**https://examle.com https://examle.com https://examle.com  https://examle.com/abc.mp4** https://examle.com https://examle.com https://examle.com

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/37zU6w/1)

Comment: If there is space between the links, [use `\S`](https://regex101.com/r/nU7rDX/1) (non-whitespace) instead of the dot which skips over.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should work for you:

```
https:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^.]+\.mp4
```